# Blender renders transparency as red?

Tags: rendering

[image]Animating a camera move that orbits around a central figure. The figure is backlit by a single light source behind it, but other than that, there are no backgrounds. Yet every time I render out (as a PNG sequence) I end up with a red background. Any idea what's causing this?

Here is the project file: [image]

Comment: Are you sure it is not a pink background, indicating a missing texture?

Comment: An interesting idea. I just attached a screenshot to the main post. The red remains in the background even as the shot moves - which suggests to me it's a global setting, not a single texture.

Comment: Doesn't look like a missing texture. Could you attach your .blend to you post? Just copy paste the link into your question by editing it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if anyone is still looking for a solution to this, but the answer for me was to set the Alpha value in the material properties to Pre multiplied instead of Straight.[image]